# Configure behaviour of DDD aggregate with strategies

Tags: entity, domain-driven-design, aggregate

I've an aggregate:

```
public class MyAggregate {

    private Country country;
    private List<SomeEntity> someEntities;

    public SomeEntity getBestMatchingSomeEntity();

}
```

My problem is, that the behaviour of getBestMatchingSomeEntity() should be configurable depending in the country, so I like to use strategies (simple Spring beans).

Im not sure how to "inject" the strategy in my entity. Normally I would use some kind of selector, but I don't want to inject a service in my entity. Or should I select the right strategy while creating the entity and inject the strategy in the entity? Or is a domain service the way to go?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this behavior used when the aggregate executes commands (methods that alter state)?

Comment: No, it's a simple "getter" which returns the matching SomeEntity from MyAggregate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that pops up in my mind.

Why don't you have the method that accepts a service like:

```
public class MyAggregate {

    private Country country;
    private List<SomeEntity> someEntities;

    public SomeEntity getBestMatchingSomeEntity(MatchingEntityService service);
}
```

Then you define the service as:

```
 public interface MatchingEntityService {

     SearchEntityStrategy strategyFor(Country country);

 }
```

In this way in your aggregate you can use the service without having the problem of injection, and the relatives serialization problems.

The `MatchingEntityService` will have the logic to select the right strategy based on the `Country` and you can keep all the different strategies separated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep the Aggregate as clean as possible, it should have behavior that is used by itself to check its invariants. Complex query behavior should be contained in some domain service.

In your case, you should have a domain service that has the strategy injected or passed as a method parameter, depending on the desired configuration.

This separation is more clear if you would have used [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html), where a read-model would have this responsibility.

Comment: Thank you Constantin. Strictly speaking it's a read-model, because it's a converted representation of an object from another system. We just read values, but don't change the state. Would you recommend a domain service anyway?

Comment: Because you don't use that `strategy` when you process a command. Like I said, if you would have used CQRS then things would be a lot clear. Anyway, if this aggregate is in fact another thing, a read-model, you could skip the domain service, like I've written in last paragraph from my answer.